# make MongoClient instance as singleton

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a java-spring web application using MongoDB as database. Below lines are used to connect to database.

```
public class SpringMongoConfig {
@Bean
public MongoClient mongo() throws Exception {
    ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(databaseUri, databasePort);
    List<MongoCredential> credentials = (databaseAuthenticationEnabled) ? Arrays.asList(
            MongoCredential.createCredential(databaseUser, authenticationDatabase, databasePassword.toCharArray()))
            : null;
    return new MongoClient(serverAddress, credentials);         
}
```

}

In another class, how will i get this mongoClient instance?

Comment: is *another class* a spring bean too?

Comment: it is a service class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `SpringMongoConfig` is actually annotated with `@Configuration` and thus:

You need to find your `another class`'s Configuration and `@Import` the `SpringMongoConfig`, something like this:

```
 @OtherConfigOfAnotherClass
 @Import(SpringMongoConfig.class)
```

And then simply `@Autowire` the MongoClient in the Service.